# recommendation for erp/dms using sql-server-express?

Tags: cms, sql-server, erp

I am searching for recommendations for a ERP/DMS/CMS type platform which runs on or alongside SQL-server express.

The ERP/DMS will be an extension to invoicing/accounting software - which runs on SQL-server express. The database is open accessible By the way ERP/DMS/CMS is what I think the relevant terms are.

Some clarifications are in order: 
I run a small utility business.
The invoicing/accounting software has been completely overhauled from a foxpro application to SQL server express.
The software is closed source, but the database is open.

Over the last 15 years I have augmented the original invoicing application with several tools such as customer relations, contract, work order and payment management, based on the central invoicing database. These tools are made with Access.

Now that that central database is changed, all the secondary tools have to been rewritten.
For the new setup, I am hoping to use a commercially or open-source available platform, limiting the conversion to customization while keeping heavy programming tasks at a minimum.

Essentially I want a front-end application system with a big emphasis on data-entry and reporting to an sql-server database backend.

It would be nice if it could be accessed from browsers allowing for mobile use. Although I don't want an online hosting solution.
The intended user base is 10-20 people with varying degrees of access.

The mobile use will be partly data-entry = filling out forms (optionboxes and limited text). 
During my search, I am always surprised that data-entry causes problems. 
As it seems a important part of a system = to feed it with data.

Initial research has mainly shown that the field of candidates is very vast - and very confusing. Alfresco, iDempiere, Dolibarr,suiteCrm, Drupal, even Wordpress, ...

I have no preference of OS, language, db as long as it can be used together with sql express.

Suggestions are welcomed